# List Settings > Form Setings > Infopath designer wont open

Tags: infopath

List Settings > Form Setings > "Modify the existing InfoPath form" is check. I click on "OK" but Infopath designer wont open.

What do I need to do so that the xsn opens in InfoPath 2010?

ps: I am logged in with sp admin account on IE 8

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have seen that problem on a couple of servers, I have never bothered to find a solution. Instead I have opened the form in InfoPath from SharePoint Designer 2010 Ribbon link (Desing Forms in InfoPath). That have always worked.

Comment: I designed the form in Infopath designer but unable to publish to a list (not library).

Answer (score 1):

Commenting the comment:

> "I designed the form in Infopath designer but unable to publish to a
>   list (not library)"

In order to publish to a list the Infopath form should be in "Sharepoint List Form" compatibility which cannot be manually chosen or changed to (like when in Intopath Filler 2010 or Web Browser)

[image]

This type of form is entered into (for already created before by the same methods) or created through

- either by clicking "Customize Form" button on ribbon in browser (under **List** tab of **List Tools** tab

  [image]
- or by choosing "Sharepoint List" form template in backstage of Infopath Designer 2010

  [image]

> List Settings > Form Setings > "Modify the existing InfoPath form" is
>   check. I click on "OK" but Infopath designer wont open.
>
> What do I need to do so that the xsn opens in InfoPath 2010?

You should have created "Sharepoint List Form" Infopath form.
You can verify that it was created by the presence of

- editifs.aspx
    _http://sharepoint_site/Lists/ListName/Item/editifs.aspx
- displayifs.aspx
    _http://sharepoint_site/Lists/ListName/Item/displayifs.aspx
- newifs.aspx
   _http://sharepoint_site/Lists/ListName/Item/newifs.aspx

alongside with present before Infopath form publishing  default Sharepoint forms:

- NewForm.aspx
    _http://sharepoint_site/Lists/ListName/Item/NewForm.aspx
- EditForm.aspx
    _http://sharepoint_site/Lists/ListName/Item/EditForm.aspx
- DispForm.aspx
    _http://sharepoint_site/Lists/ListName/Item/DispForm.aspx

in Sharepoint Designer 2010

[image]

Note that the first 3 web pages use the same (one!) Infopah form and the last 3 web pages cannot be opened at all when **List Settings** > **Form Setings** > "**Modify the existing InfoPath form**" is chosen upon Infopath form publishing

[image]

and vice versa!

Also [you are not opening Infopath Designer (for creating form templates) from Sharepoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40064/link-to-one-new-form-and-link-to-open-that-saved-form-with-workflow/40473#40473) but Infopath Filler for filling form (instances of templates) from already existing and published to Sharepoint server form templates.