# Link to ONE New Form and Link to Open That Saved Form with Workflow

Tags: workflow, infopath

Using SharePoint Online - Office 365, with SharePoint Designer and InfoPath. So, I am looking for a no code solution - if possible.

I am setting up individual client sub-sites. Each client will have an intake form to complete. I created the form in InfoPath, and set it up to create a unique file name on opening form for the first time as well as updating that form if the user re-opens and edits.

I am having some trouble though in figuring out how to lock the user in to that one form and do so with a workflow by possibly creating a link to "Begin" (to kick off the instance of the new form) and the "Edit" (after they created it) the form.

1. How can I create a link to create the InfoPath form?
2. After the client begins the form (new form), how can I create a link to just edit that one form?
3. How can I do this in a workflow?

And, is it possible to lock the user out of creating new instances of the form?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I create a link to create the InfoPath form?

Let me answer you by 2 questions:

- How do you create a link to create a MS Word document or any other file on client/remote machine using locally installed there applications?
- And how can you give a link to something non-existent, yet to be only created?

If this my question is not the answer then direct answer:
you cannot because Infopath Designer with which one creates Infopath forms is not server but client application

You can save the Infopath form template on a network share and permit to modify or fill the form

One can use Infopath Form Service to dynamically generate and render web pages with the use of Infopath forms created on client machine with client/locak Infopath Designer 2010 and then published as template to a (Sharepoint) server